# Outline for text file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding, outline

In visual-studio-code I can have a text file with folding based on tabs.
I find this a light way to keep notes.

Any ideas if there's a way to show those fold levels in the outline window.
This would be perfect for navigating the level 1 folds (maybe also 2).

Opening outline on a .txt files displays 'No symbols found in xxx.txt'.
So I'm guessing there needs to be a symbol tree defined using a textmate definition?

e.g. https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/blob/4cf1d44e5c524a4e7cf8f306085a748610413ac2/syntaxes/yaml.tmLanguage.json

BTW, switching filetype to markdown kinda works if you set edit the level 1 folds to be headings. But then you lose the ability to fold inner levels unless you also set them as lower markdown headings. This then causes the outline view to get cluttered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension [Better Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adamerose.better-outline&ssr=false#overview), add some comments for level 1 in your text document which can be displayed as outline, then it can be used for navigating the level 1.

But it does not support level 2 in your case.

Comment: Cheers Peter much appreciater